# sqlite-net-pcl crashes on synchronous init

Tags: c#, maui, sqlite-net-pcl

I created a class for managing the SQLite database in my MAUI app. I have an async method to initialize it:

```
public static async Task InitializeDatabase()
{
    _dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DB_NAME);
    _connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbPath, _openFlags);

    try
    {
        var docTableResult = await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Document>();
        var itemTableResult = await _connection.CreateTableAsync<DocumentItem>();
        var articleTableResult = await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Article>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
}
```

I'm calling this method from MauiProgram, after registering my services. When I call it by creating a new task, it runs fine:

```
Task.Run(async () => await SQLiteService.InitializeDatabase());
```

But if I call it synchronously, it crashes on the line where it creates the first table (Document) and shows no error.

```
SQLiteService.InitializeDatabase().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Why does it crash?

Comment: Running those operations synchronously is not something you should rely on. There are plenty of methods which will fail or deadlock. Also, about the lack of error information, your use of try catch is a problem. That's like a textbook example of how not to use try catch.

Comment: Can't tell exactly why it crashes, but you're kinda cheating. The method inside MauiProgram is not meant to perform long running tasks. You should mark `InitializeDatabase` as an `async void` or call it from some other methods. The reason why it doesn't crash with Task.Run is that you're not awating the call result.

Comment: But how does not awaiting affect the execution inside the method itself?

Comment: The InitializeDatabase need to use asynchronous lazy initialization to delay initialization of the database until it's first accessed, with a simple Init method that gets called by each method in the class.